# Ajustar los registros por pagina segun un input en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component

soy un poco novato en React.

Estoy tratando de poner un numero de registros, y ese numero lo obtengo de un input que está en una pagina diferente.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Productos extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imagenes: [],
      pagina: 1,
      porPagina: 9,
      maximo: 0,
    };
    this.handlePorPaginaChange = this.handlePorPaginaChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  async fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/API/getProductos.php');
      this.setState({ imagenes: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async actualizarProducto(idProd) {
    try {
      // Actualizar el producto con dicho id
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async borrarProducto(idProd) {
    try {
      // Borrar el producto con dicho id
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  handlePorPaginaChange = (e) => {
    const nuevaPorPagina = parseInt(e.target.value);
    if (isNaN(nuevaPorPagina) || nuevaPorPagina <= 0) {
      this.setState({ porPagina: 0, pagina: 1 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ porPagina: nuevaPorPagina, pagina: 1 });
    }
  };

  getPorPagina() {
    return this.state.porPagina;
  }

  render() {
    const { imagenes, porPagina } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="misProd">
        <div id="panelProd">
          <h3>Disposición de productos</h3>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor='valor'>Registros por página:</label>
          <input
            id={'valor'}
            value={porPagina}
            onChange={(e) => this.handlePorPaginaChange(e)}
            style={{ height: '30px', width: '50px', borderRadius: '20px', textAlign: 'center' }}
          />
        </div>

        <div id="displayProd">
          {Array.isArray(imagenes) ? (
            imagenes.map((imagen) => (
              <div key={imagen.id_producto}>
                <div className="productos">
                  <img src={imagen.rutaImg} alt={imagen.nombre} />
                  <p>{imagen.nombre}</p>
                  <p>{imagen.precio}€</p>
                  <button onClick={() => this.borrarProducto(imagen.id_producto)}>
                    <i className="bi bi-x"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button onClick={() => this.actualizarProducto(imagen.id_producto)}>
                    <i className="bi bi-pencil"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>Todavía no hay imágenes. Disculpen las molestias</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Productos;
```

Lo que quiero es actualizar la propiedad **porPagina** del State y ese valor lo obtengo del input que hay mas abajo.

Luego creo una instancia de esta clase en un componente

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Pagination from '../components/pagination';
import Productos from '../Admin/productos';

function ConjuntosMujer(props) {
  const [imagenes, setImagenes] = useState([]);
  const [pagina, setPagina] = useState(1);
  const registros = new Productos();
  const porPagina = registros.getPorPagina(); //solo coge el valor por defecto del constructor
  const [maximo, setMaximo] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://'+ window.location.hostname +':5000/API/getConjuntosMujer.php');
        setImagenes(response.data);
        setMaximo(response.data.length);
        console.log(porPagina);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [porPagina]);

  return (
    <section className='main'>

      <article className='imgs'>
        {Array.isArray(imagenes) ? (
          imagenes.slice((pagina - 1) * porPagina, pagina * porPagina).map((imagen) => (
            <div key={imagen.id_producto}>
              <div className='divCont'>
                <img src={imagen.rutaImg} alt="" />
                <p id='nomProd'>{imagen.nombre}</p>
                <p>{imagen.precio}€</p>
                <button id="añadir">Comprar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>Todavía no hay imágenes. Disculpen las molestias</p>
        )}
      </article>
      {maximo > porPagina && (
        <Pagination pagina={pagina} setPagina={setPagina} maximo={maximo} registrosPorPagina={porPagina} />
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

export default ConjuntosMujer;
```

Y no consigo actualizar el numero de registros por pagina, solo obtengo el valor por defecto del state.

He estado viendo videos en YouTube pero no me sirve de mucho y los ChatGPT solo lo empeora

Agradecería ayuda